# Calculate Time difference using UNIX time stamp in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, unix-timestamp

I have 2 unix time, one is todays date and other is expiration time.

- Todays Time: 1377173245 (2013-08-22 12:07:25)
- Expiration Time: 1406303166 (2014-07-25 15:46:06)

What I want to achieve is calculate remaining time to expire the listing. In current case, it should show, `11 months -- hours -- minutes -- seconds` I didn't find any good solution to calculate the difference. I doubt is it possible to calculate time difference using UNIX time system?

Thank you :-)

Comment: What do you consider  month? 30/31, what about february, I'd rather not use months in time difference.

Comment: I think you have a problem similar to as described in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/676824/365188

Comment: Hello Ozair, the question link you gave is date function I'm talking about time which show date format in UNIX

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you're looking for: [DateTime::diff](https://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

First create object with 1st date:

```
$date = new DateTime('2013-08-22 12:07:25');
```

Then use the diff method:

```
$diff = $date->diff(new DateTime('2014-07-25 15:46:06'));
```

Now if you print $diff variable, you will see the array containing values for hour, minute, day and so on.

Comment: Hello Michal, it show the following error, Call to undefined method DateTime::diff()

Comment: Oh.. I see it require php 5.3 or higher

Comment: Ya, its working. thanks a lot friend I appreciate. Also, thank you everyone who suggested the answers.

Comment: If all you need to check is whether the expiration date-time has been crossed, simply check the "invert" index from the $diff array. If its 1. then the returned interval is negative and hence the expiration limit has been crossed.

Answer (score 2):

Use `DateTime::diff`

See the doc on https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: This does not specify how to use timestamp

Answer (score 1):

Try using [datetime::diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php). Here's the example from the php.net documentation:

```
<?php
$datetime1 = date_create('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = date_create('2009-10-13');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
?>
```

It's easy to create a `DateTime` object using a timespamp. However, this solution requires PHP 5.3+.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DateTime`](https://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) class:

Example:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime();
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2014-07-25 15:46:06');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%M months, %H hours, %I minutes, and %S seconds remaining ');
```

Outputs:

```
11 months, 21 hours, 44 minutes, and 20 seconds remaining
```

Answer (score -1):

It is most definitely possible. However, you'll run into problems with months, because there are different number of days in each month, so I'll just do days, hours, minutes, and seconds below.

```
$days=($expiration-$today)/(60*60*24);
$hours=(($expiration-$today)/(60*60))%24; //the modulus operator, gets a remainder
$minutes=(($expiration-$today)/(60))%(60*60);
$seconds=($expiration-$today)/60;
```

If you need months, you'll find it easier to use [`date_diff()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php).

Comment: The DateTime classes can deal with this much more simply as you can see from the other answers.

Comment: relative, but not detracting